# Remove from line to line in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with contents:

```bsh
**** BEGIN_neofetch_files ****
#!porg-0.10
#t:1607266891
#s:353473
#f:2
#a:
#S:
#u:
#l:
#c:
#i:
#d:
**** END_neofetch_files ****

**** BEGIN_neofetch_metadata ****
maintainer="tsujan"
version="0.19.0"
homepage="https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum"
date="Mon Mar 29 04:36:41 PM CDT 2021"
**** END_neofetch_metadata ****
```

What I am trying to do is remove from line number to line number with sed. An example would be from 1 to 13 (the BEGIN and END). I already have a method for determining the line numbers. I just need to know how to delete those lines and the ones in-between. The file would look like this after:

```bsh
**** BEGIN_neofetch_metadata ****
maintainer="tsujan"
version="0.19.0"
homepage="https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum"
date="Mon Mar 29 04:36:41 PM CDT 2021"
**** END_neofetch_metadata ****
```

Comment: `sed -i.bak 1,13d myfile`

Comment: It works but it has these lines left: /usr/share/man/man1/neofetch.1|11878|
**** END_neofetch_files **** It works if I use 1,15

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i.bak 1,15d myfile` works.

Comment: So, you are not deleting lines 1 to 13, but lines 1 to 15.

Comment: I messed up on the line counting